# Flatten nested array of objects JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a nested array of objects and want to get only the child property elements of an array. This is just an example and the actual data will include a unique children property in separate indices in the array. I am only able to traverse the first array in the list.

Here is my implementation:

```js
const headers = [{
    id: "name1",
    title: "Name 1",
    children: [{
        title: "Children 1",
        child: [{
            title: "Child 1",
            onClick: "child1Click"
          },
          {
            title: "Child 2",
            onClick: "child2Click"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "CHildren 2",
        child: [{
            title: "Child 3",
            id: "child3Click"
          },
          {
            title: "Child 4",
            id: "child4Click"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "name2",
    title: "Name 2",
    children: [{
        title: "Children 3",
        child: [{
            title: "Child 5",
            onClick: "child5Click"
          },
          {
            title: "Child 6",
            onClick: "child6Click"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "CHildren 4",
        child: [{
            title: "Child 7",
            id: "child7Click"
          },
          {
            title: "Child 8",
            id: "child8Click"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "name3",
    title: "Name 3"
  },
  {
    id: "name4",
    title: "Name 4"
  }
]

console.log(_.flattenDeep(_.map(_.compact(_.map(headers, item => item.children))[0], item1 => item1.child)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Child 1",
    "onClick": "child1Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Child 2",
    "onClick": "child2Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Child 3",
    "id": "child3Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Child 4",
    "id": "child4Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Child 5",
    "onClick": "child5Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Child 6",
    "onClick": "child6Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Child 7",
    "id": "child7Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Child 8",
    "id": "child8Click"
  }
]
```

Please advice.

Edit: I was able to get the required result using console.log(*.flattenDeep(*.map(*.flattenDeep(*.compact(_.map(headers, 'children'))), 'child')))

But is there an optimized version for doing the same? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the children with `_.flatMap()`, filter out the `undefined` values, and then use `_.flatMap()` again to get the values of the `child` property:

```js
const headers = [{"id":"name1","title":"Name 1","children":[{"title":"Children 1","child":[{"title":"Child 1","onClick":"child1Click"},{"title":"Child 2","onClick":"child2Click"}]},{"title":"CHildren 2","child":[{"title":"Child 3","id":"child3Click"},{"title":"Child 4","id":"child4Click"}]}]},{"id":"name2","title":"Name 2","children":[{"title":"Children 3","child":[{"title":"Child 5","onClick":"child5Click"},{"title":"Child 6","onClick":"child6Click"}]},{"title":"CHildren 4","child":[{"title":"Child 7","id":"child7Click"},{"title":"Child 8","id":"child8Click"}]}]},{"id":"name3","title":"Name 3"},{"id":"name4","title":"Name 4"}]

const result = _.flatMap(_.compact(_.flatMap(headers, 'children')), 'child')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you're using lodash/fp, you can generate a more readable function with `_.flow()`:

```js
const fn = _.flow(
  _.flatMap('children'),
  _.compact,
  _.flatMap('child')
)

const headers = [{"id":"name1","title":"Name 1","children":[{"title":"Children 1","child":[{"title":"Child 1","onClick":"child1Click"},{"title":"Child 2","onClick":"child2Click"}]},{"title":"CHildren 2","child":[{"title":"Child 3","id":"child3Click"},{"title":"Child 4","id":"child4Click"}]}]},{"id":"name2","title":"Name 2","children":[{"title":"Children 3","child":[{"title":"Child 5","onClick":"child5Click"},{"title":"Child 6","onClick":"child6Click"}]},{"title":"CHildren 4","child":[{"title":"Child 7","id":"child7Click"},{"title":"Child 8","id":"child8Click"}]}]},{"id":"name3","title":"Name 3"},{"id":"name4","title":"Name 4"}]

const result = fn(headers)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Using lodash with `_.flow()` and `_.partialRight()`:

```js
const pr = _.partialRight;

const fn = _.flow(
  pr(_.flatMap, 'children'),
  _.compact,
  pr(_.flatMap, 'child')
)

const headers = [{"id":"name1","title":"Name 1","children":[{"title":"Children 1","child":[{"title":"Child 1","onClick":"child1Click"},{"title":"Child 2","onClick":"child2Click"}]},{"title":"CHildren 2","child":[{"title":"Child 3","id":"child3Click"},{"title":"Child 4","id":"child4Click"}]}]},{"id":"name2","title":"Name 2","children":[{"title":"Children 3","child":[{"title":"Child 5","onClick":"child5Click"},{"title":"Child 6","onClick":"child6Click"}]},{"title":"CHildren 4","child":[{"title":"Child 7","id":"child7Click"},{"title":"Child 8","id":"child8Click"}]}]},{"id":"name3","title":"Name 3"},{"id":"name4","title":"Name 4"}]

const result = fn(headers)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I got a similar code to get the following done. I did using _.compact to get the truthy values. Is there any alternative way of doing this?

Comment: I actually prefer compact. Haven't used that one in eons. See my lodash/fp solution.

Comment: The second solution looks neat. I'll check it out. Thanks mate.

Comment: Note the use of lodash/fp. It can be done using lodash, but it requires partialRight.

Comment: Do you mind getting me a solution using partialRight?